# How do I find my production keystore for Google Maps V1

Tags: android, google-maps

I have my debug keystore but now I need to deploy an app into Google Play using Google Maps v1.  How can I get a production Google maps key for V1?

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I transitioned everything to v2, you'd think if you got a debug key they'd reserve you a key or something, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [Obtaining a Google Maps Android v1 API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey)

> Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th,
>   2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
>   version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1.
>   However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and
>   new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

No, sorry, Google has stopped generating keys for v1.